# Select TOP 10 data for each day with Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have a set of data in MySQL database for a table named 'events' with a timestamp format 06/May/2017 20:30:51 in a column named 'timestamp'

Every day, the system will generate a lot of data but I would only require only 10 data being selected for each day.

Current query is:

```
$events = DB::table('events')
->select('events.id', 'events.nid', 'events.timestamp')
->orderBy('events.id','desc')
->get();
```

How can I achieve this with a query builder.

Further Explanation:

In a set of database there will be let say 100 data:
15 set of data on date 01/May/2017
20 set of data on date 02/May/2017
12 set of data on date 03/May/2017
30 set of data on date 04/May/2017
15 set of data on date 05/May/2017
8  set of data on date 06/May/2017

What I would like to achieve is a query that will select:
10 set of data on date 01/May/2017 if any
10 set of data on date 02/May/2017 if any
10 set of data on date 03/May/2017 if any
10 set of data on date 04/May/2017 if any
10 set of data on date 05/May/2017 if any
10 set of data on date 06/May/2017 if any

in a single query builder.

Comment: use `->take(10)` in the query https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Using take is for the entire query data. However I would want to select only 10 data per day for the entire query

Comment: ->where('timestamp', '>', 'some-start-date')->where('timestamp', '<', 'some-end-date')

Comment: Ryan Tuosto Thanks for your reply but this is not what i'm looking for. Ive edited the question with further explaination

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$day_start = strtotime("2017-01-01 00:00:00");
$day_end = strtotime("2017-01-01 24:59:59");

$events = DB::table('events')
   ->select('events.id', 'events.nid', 'events.timestamp')
   ->andWhere('events.timestamp', '>' , $day_start)
   ->andWhere('events.timestamp', '<' , $day_end)
   ->orderBy('events.id','desc')
   ->take(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what i'm looking for. Ive edited the question with further explaination